# Windows setting crash and slows pc

Tags: windows-10, crash, windows-10-upgrade

After installing update 20H2 from 1909 I encountered something very odd.
I run smoothly after boot for 15 minutes, then the settings app hangs and crashes.
This causes search panel to malfunction, pc to have slow performance etc...

When looking at the event viewer, I noticed an error saying:

"SystemSettings.exe stopped communicating with windows"

Has anyone experienced such a thing? How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an antivirus or any software that could have blocked its access?

Comment: I use NODE32 as antivirus and it didn't cause any issue with build 1909

Comment: Have you updated it to the current version.  AV can be compatible with one version but not another version.  Does this happen while in safe mode?

Comment: Didn't try in safe mode tbh and yes, updated to current version

Comment: This is such rubbish every application of Windows gets event id 1002 - application hang. This is so frustrating!!